# What are the HSA limits with spouse having separate health plan and me with a child?

Tags: united-states, hsa, limits, hdhp

According to the open enrollment table in my HR guide, the 2019 HSA limits are:

```
EE Only                            $3,500
EE + Spouse or EE + Child(ren)     $7,000
```

My spouse has her own HDHP insurance through her employer and we are married filing jointly.  I insure myself and my child through my employer.  Does the $7000 limit count towards the family as a whole, regardless of how they're insured?

In other words, can my spouse contribute the $3500, while I contribute $7000, or are we limited as a family to the $7000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1) You can put $7,000 into your HSA cause you insure the child. Then your spouse can't put any money into theirs.

2) You can each put $3,500 into your individual HSAs.

Either way - your maximum is always $7,000. However, your spouse can't put more than $3,500 in because it is a self-only plan.